# pandas creating M-F time series dummies

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to create a Boolean point one hot style in time series data for when the data frame hour is between 7AM and 5PM Monday through Friday? This errors out below when I add in the additional `and df.index.weekday <= 4` to the lambda function:

```
hours = pd.get_dummies(df.index.hour, prefix='hour')
df['hour'] = df.index.strftime('%H').astype('int')
df['7AM_to_5PM'] = df['hour'].apply(lambda hr : 1 if (hr > 7 and hr < 17 and df.index.weekday <= 4) else 0)
```

Error is:

```
----> 3 df['7AM_to_5PM'] = df['hour'].apply(lambda hr : 1 if (hr > 7 and hr < 17 and df.index.weekday <= 4) else 0)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This below works just fine but will also incorporate the weekend data which I dont want:

```
 df['7AM_to_5PM'] = df['hour'].apply(lambda hr : 1 if (hr > 7 and hr < 17) else 0)
```

Ultimate use case I am trying to create a seperate dataframe for this dummy variable for plotting purposes:
`df_scatter = df[['oat','electricity','7AM_to_5PM']]`

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0):

```
hours = pd.get_dummies(df.index.hour, prefix='hour')
df['hour'] = df.index.strftime('%H').astype('int')
df['day_of_week'] = df.index.dayofweek
df['7AM_to_5PM'] = df['hour'].apply(lambda hr : 1 if (hr > 7 and hr < 17) else 0)
df['weekend'] = np.where(df['day_of_week'].isin([5,6]), 1, 0)
df['Occupied_Building'] = np.where(((df['weekend'].eq(0)) & (df['7AM_to_5PM'].eq(1))), 1, 0)
```

for ultimate use case to use sns to make a scatter plot of data for an occupied building and not occupied energy use.

```
df_scatter = df[['oat','kW','Occupied_Building']]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df_scatter.plot.scatter('oat','kW', c='Occupied_Building', ylim=([0, 150]), xlim=([0, 100]), title=f'Red is occupied times 7AM-5PM kW Vs Outside Air Dry Bulb Temp', colormap='jet',figsize=(25,8), ax=ax)
ax.set_xlabel("°F")
plt.show()
```

[image]